# Java : How to get the latest (last modified) directory in a path

Tags: java, file-io, directory

I have a requirement where I need to get the latest (last modified) directory/folder in a path.

I found similar solutions for a file in a directory but not for directory in a path.

Comment: Can you please put the code what you have tried & what issue you are facing?

Comment: I have been successful to get the time of the last modified directory using this:
    `public static void getLastModifiedDir(){`
      `      File file = new File("file path");`
        `    System.out.println("last modifed:" + `
        `    new Date(file.lastModified()));`
      
    `//below code works only for files not for folders  `
 `        File[] files = file.listFiles();`
        `     if (files.length == 0) {`
                 
        `    }`
         
 `}`

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions about specific programming problems.  This is not a "gimmeh-teh-codez" site.  Questions are expected to demonstrate what you have tried and explain why it does not work (how its results differ from your expected results).  This question is merely an explanation of your intended goal, but there is no code here.  What's the *actual* problem you're running into?  Please edit your question to improve its quality.

Answer (score 1):

Find below a small snippet as an example. Proper exception and error handling needs to be added.

```
public class LastModifiedDir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String filesLocation = "... your directory to check ...";

        Path path = Paths.get(filesLocation);

        List<Path> dirs = new ArrayList<>();

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
            for (Path entry : dirStream) {
                if (Files.isDirectory(entry, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                    dirs.add(entry);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(dirs, ComparatorReverseLastModificationTime());

            System.out.println("recently changed directory: " + dirs.get(0));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // add your exception handling here
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    static Comparator<Path> ComparatorReverseLastModificationTime() {
        return new Comparator<Path>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Path o1, Path o2) {
                int compareTo = 0;
                try {
                    compareTo = Files.getLastModifiedTime(o1, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).compareTo(Files.getLastModifiedTime(o2, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // proper exception handling must go here
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
                return -compareTo;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs()`, then iterate the list and sort by `file.lastModified`.